# How to decrease Git binaries size while building Git on Docker Alpine?

Tags: git, docker, alpine-linux

I'm developing a wrapper around Git called [Elegant Git](https://github.com/bees-hive/elegant-git/) and want to have tests running on multiple Git versions. As the project uses Docker containers for testing, I've prepared a Dockerfile that installs Git from sources and got strange results:

- Apline image with Git installed from sources **> 200Mb**
- Apline image with Git installed via `apk add git` ~ **28Mb**

It reflects the size of each created binary file

```
Build version: 
18.6M   /git/usr/libexec/git-core/git
apk version: 
2.4M    /usr/libexec/git-core/git
```

**Is there a way to decrease binaries' size while building Git from sources?**

The following *Dockerfile* reproduces the behavior:

```
ARG bashversion=3.2.57
FROM bash:${bashversion}
ARG gitversion=2.26.2
WORKDIR /git

RUN apk add --no-cache curl && \
    curl --output git-${gitversion}.tar.gz \
         https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-${gitversion}.tar.gz && \
    tar -xvzf git-${gitversion}.tar.gz && \
    mkdir -p /git

RUN apk add --no-cache \
        zlib-dev \
        openssl-dev \
        curl-dev \
        expat-dev \
        perl-dev \
        python3-dev \
        pcre2-dev \
        asciidoc \
        xmlto \
        perl-error tcl tk make gcc g++ 

RUN cd git-${gitversion} && \
    make prefix=/usr DESTDIR=/git NO_GETTEXT=YesPlease NO_REGEX=YesPlease ICONV_OMITS_BOM=Yes && \ 
    make prefix=/usr DESTDIR=/git NO_GETTEXT=YesPlease NO_REGEX=YesPlease ICONV_OMITS_BOM=Yes install

RUN apk add --no-cache git && \
    echo "Build version: " && \
    du -ha /git/usr/libexec/git-core/git | sort && \
    echo "apk version: " && \
    du -ha /usr/libexec/git-core/git | sort
```

Comment: No time to write a full answer, but my guess is intermediate layers. You have to remove all unnecessary files (`.git`, source files, temporary build artifacts) in the same docker command which introduced them (RUN). Maybe a `make clean` as last step in your build command already helps. Download the source tar in your build command and delete the tar file after building.

Comment: @knittl the problem is not with the intermediate layers, it is with the size of created binaries - 18.6M vs 2.4M. And the provided Dockerfile just reproduces the issue.

Comment: I imagine debug data is not present in the apk version.  If you run `make strip` before `make install`, that will likely decrease the size of the executables.

Comment: Oh, then I misunderstood (you explicitly mentioned the image sizes). By forcing use of different layers, the image size goes down by 500M. And still not an answer, but maybe a pointer in the right direction: <https://build.alpinelinux.org/buildlogs/build-edge-x86/main/git/git-2.27.0-r0.log> has the build log for the alpine package of Git. There are lines with `git*: Package size: 18.8 MB` and `git*: Compressing data...`. Now you only need to find the build script or build runner :)

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister your suggestions works. Now the size of the built git binary is 3.0M comparing to 2.4M of apk binary. Could you please post is as the answer?

Comment: @DmytroSerdiuk Done.  Glad it helped!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I imagine debug data is not present in the apk version. If you run `make strip` before `make install`, that will likely decrease the size of the executables.

Comment: If someone is interested in the final solution, [here](https://github.com/bees-hive/elegant-git/blob/6f67027325dee574b12adfb92683664122d61c78/.workflows/bats/Dockerfile) is the final Dockerfile that install Git on Alpine-based image.